# Angularjs and Laravel Routing

Tags: angularjs, laravel, routes

Hi I am working on a project where I am using Laravel routing and AngularJs routing at the same time but the problem is when I reload the specific page laravel routing get active and angularjs routing get deactive. 
So how to prevent the pages to go for laravel routing while refesh the page?

Comment: are you using `html5` mode  in angular js?

Comment: Yes I am using html5mode